# Ad mob doesn't show up!! with everything correctly set

Tags: android

I have
onCreate()
{

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.IAB_BANNER, "a15119c131293a3");
       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
           //adLayout is a large linear layout that takes up half of the screen
       LinearLayout adLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adViewLayout);
       adLayout.addView(adView);
       adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

}

Then in manifest I have all the permissions and admob activity imported.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<activity  
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"  
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />  
        <activity
```

What could possible have gone wrong? Thank you in advance for your help. Ads simply doesn't show up.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.easyDefinition.googledefinition"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        >
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Define: "
            android:textSize = "20dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTxt2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:maxLength="90"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:hint= "The word to search"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" >         
            </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/googleSearchBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Show the definition"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.easyDefinition.googledefinition.ToolFileListView
        android:id="@+id/fileListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/adViewLayout"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

No Logcat errors

Does this count?

```
02-12 00:26:15.223: E/webview(18040): registerForStylusPenEvent onAttachedToWindow
02-12 00:26:15.223: E/webview(18040): registerForStylusPenEvent START
02-12 00:26:15.228: E/webview(18040): registerForStylusPenEvent END
```

Comment: Post the code where you have the LinearLayout with the id of adViewLayout defined. Also, when the activity starts, you will have some errors / warnings related to your ad in the logact. Copy and paste those too.

Comment: If you replace the adView with a different type of view, is that view visible?

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: I am thinking, it has to do with the space available for the size. If you look at the [Banner Sizes](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate) (switch to the Android tab), you will see it needs 468x60 _dip_. The container for the Adview LinearLayout has `android:layout_height="20dp"/>`. Change that to `wrap_content` and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed it wrap_content but the ad still doesn't show up. It is empty.

Comment: Then check the logcat. You will see some very specific entries for Admob.

Comment: I am not getting any red erros but I did get this:02-12 00:46:18.494: D/WebCore(23702): uiOverrideUrlLoading: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returnstrue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first run AdMob it is possible that nothing will show up because the server needs to "warm up" to start delivering ads to your app. Afterwards, it is still possible that ads won't show up because there is no ad inventory. In particular, it is possible that there is no ad inventory for the country you are testing your app from.

**edit re:warm up**
From my experience the first few ad requests from an app often fail. This is probably because the server needs to allocate resources to serve ads to an app it hasn't seen before or hasn't seen recently.

The [AdMob documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals) has this comment:

> The very first time AdMob sees your publisher ID it may take up to two minutes to receive an ad. This initial two minute lag will recur every time the ID goes unused for 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I live in US and I have already added the app in the admob website though. I wish it is just that it has to warm up. Do you see any errors? Thanks

Comment: Try adding the following `adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);` *before* `adView.loadAd`, run on emulator and see if ads show up.

Comment: Wow, it is working with the emulator. I was testing in Galaxy Note 2 before. Do you know what is the difference between the two testing devices? Shouldn't it work for real devices too?

Comment: In this case it is either the "warming up" issue or lack of ad inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add this in your manifest.xml

```
 <meta-data
    android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS"
    android:value="true" />
```